# Flatten an array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have some simple code that looks like this:

```
fruit.each do |c|
  c.each do |key, value|
    puts value
  end
end
```

This works fine, but it feels un-ruby like. My goal is to take this array:

```
[{"fruit_id"=>"1"}, {"fruit_id"=>"2"}, {"fruit_id"=>"3"}]
```

And convert it to this:

```
[ "1", "2", "3" ]
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If it's in Rails or if you have [to_proc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Symbol.html) defined, you can go a little bit shorter than @toholio's solution:

```
arr = [{"fruit_id"=>"1"}, {"fruit_id"=>"2"}, {"fruit_id"=>"3"}]
out = arr.map(&:values).flatten # => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: I wish I could approve both - this is great too!

Comment: Well, they're actually the same solution really. :)

Comment: for 1.9.3 there is 
arr.flat_map(&:values)

Answer (score 21):

So you want each hash to be converted to its values then joined with the values from the other hashes?

```
in = [{"fruit_id"=>"1"}, {"fruit_id"=>"2"}, {"fruit_id"=>"3"}]
out = in.map{ |item| item.values }.flatten
```

`out` will then be `["1","2","3"]`.

Answer (score 14):

@wombleton @aronchick I suggest to use "flat_map(&:values)" instead "map(&:values).flatten" for better performance.

```
arr = [{"fruit_id"=>"1"}, {"fruit_id"=>"2"}, {"fruit_id"=>"3"}]
out = arr.flat_map(&:values)
```

Take a look here for more info: http://gistflow.com/posts/578-use-flat_map-instead-of-map-flatten

Answer (score 5):

if you use map!, you don't create another array in memory

```
a.map! {|h| h.values}.flatten
```

this can be also written as

```
a.map!(&:values).flatten!
```

also looking at the comments, theres a method in ruby 1.9.3 called `flat_map` (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) that will do the map and the flatten in one call.

```
a.flat_map(&:values)
```

Comment: ...or at least not use a local variable.

Answer (score 4):

```
a.inject([]) { |mem,obj| mem += obj.values }
```

Comment: injecting into an empty array is also known as collect (or map).  see other answers here.

Comment: Use << instead of += to append to arrays.  It will be slightly faster as you won't be creating all those new array objects.

Comment: << and += are not the same. If you want to use "<<" you will have to flatten again. Anyways its just nitpick.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't change much, but you could use `map`:

```
x.map do |fruit|
    fruit.each { |k,v| puts v }
end
```